# background-size: cover only fits width

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-size

I have an "horizontal" image as background (it's 2048x1148).

I set `background:url("") no-repeat scroll center top / cover` and in desktop mode everything is ok. In mobile though I can't get the background-image to scale and automatically cover the height. Shouldn't `background-size:cover` do it automatically?

[image: Mobile view] [image: Desktop view]

[Here](http://inflationhistory.com/)'s the live site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your page cover the hole viewport:

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

or use `min-height`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Was that easy.. I always forget to check viewport styling. I'm accepting this as it was the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under your `html` styling in the CSS file add a `min-height: 100%;`, I tried it and it worked.

```
html, body {
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`html` & `body` tags should be 100% height and remove margin from body:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```